# How to attach a delegate when adding a new record

Tags: javascript, delegates

I have a form where i attach the OnChange method like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#fieldId').change(function () {
    ...
   }
}
```

But i have the case when i add a new record with the Id "fieldId" from a function as

```
function addTeamMember() {
var newItem= "<input  id='fieldId' type='text'>"
$("#other").append(newItem);
...
}
```

But the Change is not fired when i change the newly added field. Can somebody help me with an idea?

Thanks.

Comment: For a start, don't use the same `id` for multiple elements (even when created dynamically)

Answer (score 2):

Change the onchange event listener to:

```
$('body').on('change', '#fieldId', function () {
  // ...
}
```

you can replace the 'body' with any container that is wrapping the dynamically added DOM element. This way, you delegating the event to existing or not existing yet elements.

Comment: The better approach would be to bind as closest as possible to the elements (usually to their container element) and not to `body`.

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks!

Comment: since I dont know his DOM structure, I stated 'body' and also stated below that all he needs is some container around the DOM element